# Tensorflow model 4 times bigger in GPU memory than Caffe model

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, tensorflow-serving

I have converted Caffe model to Tensorflow. 
TF model allocates 4 times more memory for the mode SERVING than caffe deployment model, using flag

```
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
```

Is it normal situation? Have anyone faced with this problem?